# eta eta squared

Tags: r, correlation

I have 4 variables to correlate (all 4 of them ordinal)
I have used Spearman to test but I want to use an additional method to support my conclusion about the correlation

I heard that I could use Eta and eta-squared (I found the "lsr" package but I don't know how to use it). is there any other option (based on Eta or otherwise)

I am open for suggestions

here is my code

```
x=rep(1:10, 50)
x=matrix(x,nrow=125, ncol=4)
cor(x,method="spearman")
```

Comment: Applying additional methods to the same data sometimes will be viewed as *reducing* support for the conclusion, because it suggests you are fishing for a procedure to confirm a preconceived result rather than supplying an objective analysis of the data.  Could you therefore explain why you think your conclusion requires any additional support?

Comment: I am just wonder whether using an additional technique would support further (by giving the same results) the conclusion (basically showing the relationship through two different angles)

Comment: A neat visualization (e.g. a mosaic plot) could bring additional insights.

Comment: I did a spearman with mosaic plot. my boss is happy so I am happy! thanks a lot everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using additional techniques to further support your findings, which, as Whuber mentions, can be misleading, why not instead test the null that the rank correlations are $0$? See [wikipedia on spearman rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient#Determining_significance) on how to test your hypothesis for 2 vectors to get a sense of the approach.

For multiple pairwise correlations at once, you need to be careful about what you want to test, and be careful about multiple hypothesis testing problems. Using `R`, check out the `psych` package, and in particular, the function `corr.test` ([link to documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/1.9.12.31/topics/corr.test)).

Comment: Testing unplanned hypotheses seems worse than looking at additional descriptive figures.

Comment: Although I agree that testing conditional on observing is problematic, by that argument, any time someone asks "I want to test some feature of my data and was wondering how I could test it," would the answer be "since you already shared info about the feature, you can't test it anymore"? Also, depending on what extent the additional descriptions are related to the first one, you're using the same data, so presumably will run into the same problems.